# How to get data from dynamic row

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Is it possible to get data after second symbol `;`? 
For example I have this XML:

```
<document>
    <line>H;1F;ss;232</line>
    <line>H2;1F;sss;232e</line>
    <line>H;15F5;sds;232sa;23</line>
    <line>Hh;1Fs;scs;232ds</line>
</document>
```

result should be:

```
<document>
    <line>ss</line>
    <line>sss</line>
    <line>sds</line>
    <line>scs</line>
</document>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two solutions: an XSLT 1.0 solution using FXSL and an XSLT 2.0 solution. Extensive explanation and a link to FXSL is provided.

Comment: Was my answer useful to you.? Or did you have any problems applying the solution? If yes, what are these problems?

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchet: thanks for answer, it is what I need. because i have about 10 symbols ";" and it's difficult to find it with substring-before and after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I. An XSLT 1.0 solution using FXSL**:

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
  exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
   <xsl:import href="strSplit-to-Words.xsl"/>
   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
     <document>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="line">
      <xsl:variable name="vwordNodes">
        <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-words">
          <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="."/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters" 
                          select="';'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <line>
       <xsl:value-of select="ext:node-set($vwordNodes)/*[3]"/>
      </line>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<document>
    <line>H;1F;ss;232</line>
    <line>H2;1F;sss;232e</line>
    <line>H;15F5;sds;232sa;23</line>
    <line>Hh;1Fs;scs;232ds</line>
</document>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<document>
   <line>ss</line>
   <line>sss</line>
   <line>sds</line>
   <line>scs</line>
</document>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **We use the `str-split-to-words` template from the [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net) library** to split the string value of every `line` element.. Note that it allowis not only a single character, but multiple characters to be specified in its `pDelimiters` parameter. In this case we specify only `';'`.
2. **The result is captured in a variable as an RTF. We convert it to ordinary tree using the `ext:node-set()` extension function**. If your XSLT processor doesn't implement `ext:node-set()` look in its documentation what is the name and namespace of the `xxx:node-set()` extension that this particular XSLT processor implements.
3. **From the thus obtained tree, we only select and output the 3rd element**. Note that this is a short XPath expression and the same short XPath expression would be used even if we wanted the 20th element -- just the index would be 20. This is impossible to achieve in a short and neat form using just a series of `substring-after()` functions.

**II. Here is a short and easy XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <document>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </document>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="line">
  <document>
   <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., ';')[3]"/>
  </document>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is aplied on the provided XML document**:

```
<document>
    <line>H;1F;ss;232</line>
    <line>H2;1F;sss;232e</line>
    <line>H;15F5;sds;232sa;23</line>
    <line>Hh;1Fs;scs;232ds</line>
</document>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<document>
      <document>ss</document>
      <document>sss</document>
      <document>sds</document>
      <document>scs</document>
</document>
```

Comment: I removed my XSLT 2.0 answer, because the use of `tokenize` is obviously much more suitable here. XSLT 1.0 good alternative also provided. +1

Answer (score 2):

Use `substring-before` and `substring-after` functions, i.e.:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="line">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(., ';'), ';'), ';')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<document>
    <line>ss</line>
    <line>sss</line>
    <line>sds</line>
    <line>scs</line>
</document>
```

Comment: There is no function to find the second position of ";" to avoid substring before and after?

Comment: @Petras, All XPath 1.0 string functions: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions

Comment: @Petras, I think there is no XSLT 1.0 way to simplify this expression, unless you use EXSLT.